# How to print a list of lists

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to print a specific list, but it doesn't work

```
let rec listes_paires l = match l with
    | [] -> []
    | x :: r -> if List.length x mod 2 = 0 then (x :: (listes_paires r))
    else ((x@x):: (listes_paires r));;

List.iter print_int (listes_paires [[]; [1];[1;2];[1;2;3];[];[5;4;3;2;1]]);;
```

Error message says :

```
Line 5, characters 20-74:
Error: This expression has type int list list
       but an expression was expected of type int list
       Type int list is not compatible with type int 
val listes_paires : 'a list list -> 'a list list = <fun>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not trying to print a list, but a list of lists. The type of `listes_paires`, as you point out yourself, is `'a list list -> 'a list list`

You can print a list of lists just by adding another `List.iter` to iterate over the inner lists as well:

```
List.iter (List.iter print_int) (listes_paires [[]; [1];[1;2];[1;2;3];[];[5;4;3;2;1]]);;
```

Comment: I might suggest cleaning up some parens with `[[]; [1];[1;2];[1;2;3];[];[5;4;3;2;1]] |> lists_paires |> List.iter (List.iter print_int)`. This also makes the code read a bit nicer left to right.